# In Apache Jmeter 3.0 : unable to file upload after inserting any body in http request; you cannot switch because

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

In Jmeter 3.0 ver,

I entered body data of HTTP Request, when I tried to click file upload, I get:

"You cannot switch because data cannot be converted to Target tab data, empty data to switch"

but in previous version jmeter 2.12 , 2.11 i can enter body data and do file upload .. Anybody know workaround for this or why i'm facing this issue in jmeter 3.0 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Do8VE.jpg)??

Comment: First, clear data (take backup) in "Body Data" tab, and add the data in "Parameters" tab and then switch to "File Upload" tab to input file. you can switch b/w Parameters and File Upload tab.

Comment: @Naveen why not make an answer instead of just a comment ? Thx

Comment: @Naveen Actually,pls understand :), my purpose is to add data in "body data" tab  and then switch to "File Upload" tab for input. In previous version , we can do it but jmeter 3 version the design changed....Please compare the previous version with jmeter 3 version.....

Comment: Anyone please suggest me workaround..

Comment: I understood your question and what I mentioned was a work around.  because you really can't use "Body Data" and "File Upload" tab in combination but you can use "Parameters" and "File Upload" tab in combination. Keeping data in "Body Data" or "Parameters" tab are same. I would suggest you go through the following link  and refer File Path section, http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request

Comment: what is the data type that "Body Data" combines? If just key-value pairs, you can convert it Parameters tab. Share the Body Data and File Upload screenshots to clear understanding of the problem.

Comment: @Naveen : it not working in the way you directed me.. Actually, my post data value is something like this
{
 "updatedAt": "${pCurrentDate}T00:00:00.000Z",
 "groupType": "master", 
 "status": "active",
}

when i tried to convert as per parameter tab 

 my request is passing in such a way that 
updatedAt=2016-10-18T00:00:00.000Z&groupType=master&status=active....

Comment: So, workaround which you suggested is not working.

Comment: try by copying entire JSON into "Value" field and leave "Name" field empty in parameters tab. Let me know the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try by copying entire JSON into "Value" field and leave "Name" field empty in parameters tab.